# Haproxy Certficate revocation list (crl) modification requires service reload?

Tags: haproxy

Haproxy Certficate revocation list (crl) modification requires service reload ?

```
HAProxy version 1.6.1, released 2015/10/20
```

Please let us know any other options/alternatives without restarting HAProxy service.

Comment: Unrelated to this issue, note that you should also upgrade to 1.6.11.  Numerous bugfixes have been applied since 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

All of the SSL-related files are only loaded at startup and reload.  Changes to the files between reloads are not detected.

There isn't an alternative to this behavior.

Comment: What is the command for reload the configuration changes without restarting the service ?

Comment: Typically it's `sudo service haproxy reload`.  This starts a new HAProxy process which validates the config, begins listening on the sockets, and signals the old process to terminate after any requests in progress are finished.

Comment: Please can you share the instructions to run HAProxy as a service. so that I can 'call sudo service haproxy reload'. Currently I am running HAProxy  with 'haproxy -f haproxy.cfg'.

Comment: I'll have to look for that.  My setups are automated.  If you are not running as a service, it should be this: `haproxy -f haproxy.cfg -D -sf $(pidof haproxy)` where `-D` means run as a daemon and `-sf` means "signal finish" -- tell the other process to finish current requests gracefully and then terminate.  `-sf` must be the last option, followed by `$(pidof haproxy)`, which returns the pid of the current process.  See https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/doc/management.txt.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more doubt regarding HAProxy run as service. How can i avoid user interaction[It seeks the certificate password] when it automatically starts.